# pyQgis snap-symbol doesn’t show

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a script that prints coordinates on mouse klick including snapped coordinates if snap is active. The strange thing is that there’s no symbolism on the canvas that shows that you are snapping on a point or other things.

Does it have to be activated somehow, if yes then how?